# What are good link recommendation sites for testers?

Tags: learning

For developers, there are many good link recommendation site like [Dzone](http://www.dzone.com/) or [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/).  Are there any similar sites exclusively for testers?

Comment: Hi Buu Ngyuyen, welcome to SQA.  You asked a reasonable question, but it is not the sort we encourage here. Please take a look at http://sqa.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask for some guidelines on the kinds of questions we encourage/discourage.  That said, I would like to think that *this* is a good site to ask specific questions about testing.  I hope to see more questions (and answers) from you here.

Comment: This is highly recommended site for testers :)

Comment: @user246 thanks for your note.  To be clear, I'm not asking about discussion sites for testers (which this site is), I'm asking about link recommendation sites, where testers can vote/read interesting links shared by others.  This is an *non-subjective* *answerable* question that I *actually* want to have answer for.  So I really don't see why it doesn't comply with the guidelines mentioned.

Comment: @Buu Nguyen Thank you for the clarification.  Would you mind defining, in a *non-subject way*, what a *good* link recommendation site is?  That way, people who answer your question will use "good" in the same way that you do.  "Good" is usually considered a subject term, but perhaps you do not mean it that way.

Comment: Could be that there aren't enough for this to be a viable site. I dont know of any - I hang out on Hacker News, occasionally reddit but I couldn't see either of those sites working *just* for testing links. So, I think the answer to your question is "There is no site" - if you want to build one, feel free

Comment: @user246 why do I feel like you're nitpicking my word ;)?  I provided 2 examples of what I consider good link recommendation sites in my question.  They are the benchmark for what I meant by "good".  I may be new to this particular SE space, but I have been with SO for several years so I think I know the basic of appropriate questioning.  Should we focus on being helpful rather than being pedantic?

Comment: @PhilK that seems to be the case, I did my homework but couldn't find any, that's why I asked here, or else somebody's going to send me to the lmgtfy :)

Comment: Perhaps I was nitpicking.  If anyone wants to discuss this further, let's move the thread to Meta.

Answer (score 3):

I have a page that aggregates blogs from many testers.
Go here http://www.allthingsquality.com/ and click the "What People Are Writing" tab.

I also frequent SQAForums.com and softwaretestingclub.com

Answer (score 1):

I follow the below 4

1. http://www.testingmentor.com/imtesty/
2. http://testingjeff.wordpress.com/
3. http://lisacrispin.com/wordpress/
4. http://www.stickyminds.com/